# onResize does not called

Tags: java, gwt, onresize

How to write a widget which reacts on resizing?

The following does not work. onResize() called only once at the beginning. Latter changing browser windows size does not cause this method to be called, despite the fact that DIVs are resized.

```
public class MyWidget extends SimpleLayoutPanel {

private Label label;

public MyWidget() {
    label = new Label("A");
    add(label);
}

@Override
public void onResize() {
    super.onResize();
    int width = label.getElement().getClientWidth();
    int height = label.getElement().getClientHeight();
    int fontsize = (width>height?height:width);
    if( fontsize > 0 ) {
        DOM.setStyleAttribute(label.getElement(), "font-size", Integer.toString(fontsize)+"px");
    }
}
```

}

and main module

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    MyWidget myWidget = new MyWidget();
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(myWidget.getElement(), "position", "fixed");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(myWidget.getElement(), "top", "0px");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(myWidget.getElement(), "left", "0px");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(myWidget.getElement(), "bottom", "0px");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(myWidget.getElement(), "right", "0px");

    RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
    rootPanel.add(myWidget);


}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Version based on ResizComposite also does not work. In this case onResize never called at all.

```
public class MyWidget extends ResizeComposite  {

private Label label;

public MyWidget() {
    label = new Label("A");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(label.getElement(), "position", "fixed");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(label.getElement(), "top", "0px");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(label.getElement(), "left", "0px");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(label.getElement(), "bottom", "0px");
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(label.getElement(), "right", "0px");

    SimpleLayoutPanel simpleLayoutPanel = new SimpleLayoutPanel();
    simpleLayoutPanel.add(label);

    initWidget(simpleLayoutPanel);
}

@Override
public void onResize() {

    int width = label.getElement().getClientWidth();
    int height = label.getElement().getClientHeight();
    int fontsize = (width>height?height:width);
    if( fontsize > 0 ) {
        DOM.setStyleAttribute(label.getElement(), "font-size", Integer.toString(fontsize)+"px");
    }

    super.onResize();
}
```

}

Comment: Does `RootPanel` implement `ProvidesResize`?

Comment: Looks like not. But can I use something other than RootPanel for root panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add to a `ProvidesResize` widget (`RootLayoutPanel`, `ResizeLayoutPanel`) or a `HeaderPanel` for the `RequiresResize` to be honored. See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Resize

Comment: The panel I used (SimpleLayoutPanel) does ProvidesResize. Why doesn't it work then?

Comment: I have used RootLayoutPanel instead of RootPanel and it worked! Thanks